# Migrating SSL enable mySQL and IIS to Cloud Server

Tags: mysql, ssl, iis, cloud

Is there any cloud hosting available where following points to be take care.

- I had SSL enabled mySQL 5.7 database in my local datacenter and it
  can be accessed from LAN and Internet using vb.net desktop
  application.
- Also I had IIS in that server for reporting (asp.net).

Is there any cloud hosting possible where entire database (with SSL) and IIS can be migrate.

Comment: You can migrate the .NET web app or service to Azure App Service. Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/migration/app-service

Comment: But how can I migrate SSL enabled mySQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/mysql/migrate/mysql-on-premises-azure-db/04-planning) is about migrating data from on-premises MySQL to Azure Database.

In addition to the application impact of migrating to SSL-based communication, the SSL/TLS connection type is also a factor to consider. After creating an Azure Database for MySQL database, review SSL settings and read [SSL/TLS connections in the Azure Database for MySQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-ssl-connection-security) article to learn how TLS settings affect your security posture.